# How to access my bug tracker by clicking a bug's ID in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, issue-tracking, bug-tracker

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio such that bugs mentioned in source code comments open up my bug tracker when clicked?

[TortoiseSVN provides this feature](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html), and allows you to specify a bug tracker URL with a bug-ID placeholder to open up. Also, the pattern of mentioned bugs can be configured via regex.

My google Kung Fu does not suffice for this quest. The closest I could get was the [linkify Add-In](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15188/Linkify-Add-in-for-Visual-Studio). However, it requires a certain prefix syntax to identify bug numbers, which appears overly complicated when compared to the TortoiseSVN approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Assist (commercial) has the [Source Links](https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W754) feature, which allows for regex patterns to be recognized in code comments and to open up an application or browser. Until mid 2017, Source Links was available as a standalone extension for free and is still available in the [Visual Studio Gallery](https://www.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/073f26d5-a44d-4733-a729-78cbbf4d622f/viewReviews/Reviews).